# How to create pointer to file inside zip archive

Tags: python, memory, zip

I've got a lot of zip files which contain .mdb databases I'm converting to .csv. Im using zipfile and pypyodbc as my libraries. I'd like to avoid extracting each zip file, processing the contained database, and then deleting the file. What I'd like to do is inflate the file I care about into memory, and then somehow pass that file in memory to the database parser. My problem is that the database library requires a file directory as input. Can I give it a memory address, or is that a made-up thing? My other alternative is to extract each file and save it as a temp file, which I can parse, and then let the computer handle later.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you run on MS Windows and that all the processing of database file happens before the script terminates, you can use `tempfile` standard Python module. For details see [PMoW](http://pymotw.com/2/tempfile/).

Advantage of using of `tempfile` is, the files and / or directories can be automatically removed after your script terminates.

This approach would work on Linux too.